# How to correctly set up the Facebook App Page of a Rails app?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, capybara, phantomjs, facebook-login, poltergeist

I have the very common problem (it's so common, there must be a tag for it) of:

> Given URL is not allowed by the Application configuration.: One or more of the given URLs is not allowed by the App's settings. It must match the Website URL or Canvas URL, or the domain must be a subdomain of one of the App's domains.

This occurs in the following situation - I write rspec/capybara specs. A few of these specs test that certain links are redirecting correctly. The links in questions are a subdomain of myapp: http://support.myapp.com. (I am using the [Uservoice](https://www.uservoice.com/g/) service but I don't think this is related).

So I have the following configuration:

- production app is running at https://myapp.com
- I run locally my app on `http://localhost:3000/`
- I have set my testing port this way: `Capybara.server_port = 42082`

One of the tests, where I have the problem, is this one:

```
scenario 'is redirected to feedback page in a new tab after clicking on feedback button' do
  within('.menu-wrapper') { click_on I18n.t('shared.header.help') }
  new_tab = page.driver.window_handles.last
  page.within_window(new_tab) do
    expect(current_url).to eq 'http://support.myapp.com/'
  end
end
```

The test passes, but in the console I get the message, mentioned at the beginning. On my Facebook App page, as far as I have understood from the many SOs I have read, the fields that are releveant to my problem are (I also provide their current state):

Under Settings/Basic tab:

- App Domains - empty. I tried to put `localhost` here, but it complains that this is a top level domain. So I tried several other versions like `localhost.com` or `myapp.com`. When I do this I edit my hosts file to `127.0.0.1 localhost.com`.
- Canvas URL - `http://localhost:3000/?origin=facebook&utm_campaign=fb&utm_source=fb`
- Secure canvas URL - `https://localhost:3000/?origin=facebook&utm_campaign=fb&utm_source=fb`
- Site URL - I don't have this field at all. For various tests I have "enabled" it by clicking "+ Add Platform" => Website

Under Settings/Advanced tab:

- Valid OAuth redirect URIs - empty

So I tried several combinations with these fields, as I have been troubleshooting the problem the whole day. Some of the conclusions I have reached are:

- during the test the url, which causes the problem is either `http://localhost:42082` or http://support.myapp.com. Unfortunately, the error message does not tell me which of these two causes the issue.
- I tried with localhost:42082 by using the following values, but that didn't work:

  - App domains: `localhost.com` - I also edit my hosts file, as I mentioned above;
  - Canvas URL/Secure Canvas URL - change the port from 3000 to 42082
  - Site URL: `http://localhost.com:42082/`
  - Valid OAuth redirect URIs - `http://localhost:42082/`
- I suspect the problem is actually from http://support.myapp.com/ This is not only a support page, but also a feedback page. There is an option to vote for new app features. If I visit the link without previously being logged in my app locally and I click on a vote button, I get a field like this:

[image: Uservoice voting]

When I was previously logged in I can directly vote, so I guess that visiting http://support.myapp.com does trigger some Facebook callbacks.

What values should I use in my Facebook App page to get the Given URL message away? Do you have any other troubleshooting ideas?

Comment: It's a bad practice to rely on external services in your tests. Instead you should mock such requests with webmock or similar

Comment: I can't understand how you are linking to `support.myapp.com` using `localhost` as your server URL.
1. Buy and authorize testmyapp.com in Facebook,
2. Redirect testmyapp.com using `/etc/hosts` to `localhost`,
3. Write your tests against it.

Comment: @MikDiet: As a rule of thumb, of course, but it's an acceptance test, isn't it reasonable to check if the app works in the real environment, without mocks nor stubs?